# Looping through json to create table

Tags: jquery, json, nested-loops

Maybe I'm doing this a bad way, but I was trying to loop through the json to create a table. Coding it without the loop works and I can loop through with one loop but if I add a nested one it doesn't create rows. Am I doing this right or am I missing something?

```
for(var i = 3; i < 17; i++){

   $('.one').append("<tr>");

   for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){

       $('.one').append("<td>" + obj.values[i][j] + "</td>" );    

    }

    $('.one').append("</tr>");
}
```

I hope it's not a simple typo I'm overlooking but I've several ways and can get it to work by hard coding j and making the line longer. I'm still pretty new and this was my first successful ajax call. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: where your json data structure? can you show it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery .append() does not append individual open and closing tags to the DOM.  It *appends* a whole element - open and closing tag.  In your code, each time you call append(), it's overwriting the previous ouput.

Here's a possible solution:

for(var i = 3; i < 17; i++){

```
$('.one').append("<tr>");

for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){

    $('.one tr').html("<td>" + obj.values[i][j] + "</td>");    

 }
```

}

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know the append needed to add the entire tag for it to work. For my code I put:

 $('.one').append("<tr></tr>");

 in the outer loop and used:

 $('.one tr:last').append("<td>" + obj.values[i][j] + "</td>" );
 
on the inner loop. The code works now and it's a lot smaller. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! It's always good when you can reduce the amount of code as well!